# Tips For Golfing In Groovy

Tags: code-golf, tips

As I have seen many questions asking tips for golfing in their interested language, I decided to ask for my favorite language: Groovy. People can give some tips and tricks that will be used in golfing with Groovy.

Comment: Well this isn't very popular, is it :-(

Comment: @Alison : I feel Bad, as there is no Golf tip for Groovy in this site :(

Comment: Do you have any tips to start us off?

Answer (score 5):

I'm new to this whole golfing thing, this is what I got so far:

Use Closures not functions:

```
def a(b){print b}
```

is longer than

```
a={print it}
```

You can use a negative index in arrays and lists as an alias for size()-

```
c = "abc"
d = ["a", "b", "c"]

assert c[c.size()-1] == c[-1]
assert c[c.size()-2] == c[-2]
assert d[d.size()-1] == d[-1]
assert d.last() == d[-1]
```

The spread operator is a shortcut for collect:

```
assert d*.size() == d.collect{it.size()}
```

For sorting use the spaceship operator:

```
e = [54,5,12]
assert e.sort{a,b->a<=>b}==e.sort{a,b->a<b?-1:+1}
assert e.sort{a,b->a<=>b}==e.sort{a,b->if (a>b) {return(-1)} else {return(+1)}}
```

Edit Conversions:

```
assert "123" as int == "123".toInteger()
```

Comment: if on something listish the `*.X` spread operator can often be written as `.X`

Answer (score 3):

As Groovy is a somewhat verbose language, you could use Groovys MOP to shorten method calls.

The following snippet for example would pay off after the fourth usage:

```
''.metaClass.r<<{i->(int)Math.random()*i}
''.r(12)
```

Tip golfing edit:

```
0.metaClass.r<<{i->(int)Math.random()*i}
0.r(12)
```

Or, you know:

```
r={(int)Math.random()*it}
r(12)
```

Answer (score 2):

### `grep` is short and works on several problems

get the chars of a string as a list with spaces and without leading elements: `'ABC XYZ'.grep()` returns `[A, B, C,  , X, Y, Z]`

grep with regexp is shorther than converting to upper case, if required: `it.grep(~/(?i)$c/)` instead of `it.toUpperCase().grep(c)`

Comment: `'ABC XYZ'as Set` is one character shorter and works in most of the same places

Answer (score 2):

**Getting An Array from a List of Objects**

If you have a list of objects like:

```
def users = [[user:'A',id:1],[user:'B',id:2],[user:'C',id:3]]
```

You can generate an ArrayList with a certain property using:

```
def userIds = users*.id // [1, 2, 3] no explicit loops!
```

**BONUS: Groovy... on Rails!**

Well, in [Grails Framework](https://grails.org/) we must get many values from a [select with multiple attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp). You can use loops, flatten and other programming more typical structures, but you can save some lines. If you have a select like:

```
<select id="users" multiple="true" name="users">
    <option value="193">User A</option>
    <option value="378">User B</option>
    <option value="377">User C</option>
</select><%-- No Grails tags for now --%>
```

Then, in your controller you can simple write:

```
def aListOfUsers = User.getAll(params.list('userIds'))
```

Comment: Would this question accept Grails golfing tips? I confess I'm afraid of downvote snipers...

Comment: Don't be afraid, PCG is full of extremely nice people :)